# Can't read txt file correctly to PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, text-files

I have working script that shows YouTube videos on page but I need it to read addresses in array from separate(txt) file. I tried several solutions but have not yet found a single working one.
Any help from smarter people!

My working code is using array like this:

```
$video = array('JObJ7vuppGE', 'BsmE6leTbkc', 'zWtj4TEVLvU');// array of youtube videos
```

What I planning to use instead:

```
$tube = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/youtube.txt';// IDs of youtube videos inside

$lines = file($tube);

foreach($lines as $line_num => $line)

$video = array($line);// array of youtube videos

$v = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\_]/", "", $_GET["v"]); // make sure "v" parameter is sanitized

if(!empty($v) && in_array($v, $video))  //check if parameter "v" is empty and is yours video
{ 
    echo '<object width="853" height="505"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/' . $v . '&hl=en_US&fs=1&hd=1&color1=0xe1600f&color2=0xfebd01"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/' . $v . '&hl=en_US&fs=1&hd=1&color1=0xe1600f&color2=0xfebd01" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="853" height="505"></embed>
    </object>';
}
else
{
    foreach($video as $v)
    {
        echo '<div class="tube">
            <a href="/sites/tube.php?v=' . $v . '" class="thickbox">
                <img style="border: 2px solid #000; margin: 5px;" alt="" src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/' . $v . '/default.jpg"/>
            </a>';

            $xmlData = simplexml_load_string(utf8_encode(file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' . $v . '?fields=title,yt:recorded')));
            $title = (string)$xmlData->title;
            $entry = $xmlData;

            $namespaces = $entry->getNameSpaces(true);
            $yr = $entry->children((string)$namespaces['yt']);

            // get <yt:recorded> node for date and replace yyyy-mm-dd to dd.mm.yyyy
            $year = substr($yr->recorded, 0, 4); 
            $month = substr($yr->recorded, 5, 2);
            $day = substr($yr->recorded, 8, 2);
            $recorddate = $day . "." . $month . "." . $year;

            echo '<p>' . $recorddate . '<br>' . $title . '<br>
            </p>
        </div>'; 
    }
}
```

unfortunately I am able to read only first line of txt file. At least I can only show the first video in page. My approach is obviously wrong.
And don`t tell, I now my code is mess. Feel free to modify and improve it, as long as it still works as planned.

Comment: If you don't mind, add the language of script in question title and tag.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do, or what's currently failing in the code you've got at the moment. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Don't post your working code. Post the code you've tried using to read from the text file into the array. That's the bit you want help with, so that's the bit we need t see.

Answer (score 0):

I just copied your code across to my local install of XAMPP.

Without a 'v' parameter in the Query String, a list of videos were shown, each displaying a thumbnail and title and within a link which redirected back to the same page, but with a 'v' parameter included.

Clicking the thumbnail loaded the page showing a YouTube player for the selected video.

I see no problems here...

Answer (score 0):

what i understand from your question you want to read video id from multiple files and combine it into one php array? AM i correct?

Also i suggest using Zend_gdata api for youtube functionality its simple with many other options you can try

Answer (score 0):

I think the main idea / question was to store the ids in a txt file and read them rather than having them stored in an array right?

```
<?php

/**
 * @author - Sephedo
 * @for - dogcat @ Stackoverflow
 * @question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936958/cant-read-txt-file-correctly-to-php-array
 */

$filename = "youtube.txt";

// Open the file
if( $handle = @fopen( $filename, "r") )
{
    // Cycle each line until end
    while(! feof( $handle ) )
    {
        $line = fgets($handle); // Read the line

        $youtube[] = $line;
    }
}

if(! isset( $youtube ) ) $youtube = array();

foreach( $youtube as $videoId )
{
    echo $videoId; // Etc etc etc.....
}

?>
```

Comment: You are correct. I managed finally to read txt file with each youtube array stored in separate line. Not sure if it`s best solution but used code like this.  $tube = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/lehele/vids/youtube2012.txt';
 $fp = @fopen($tube, 'r');  
if ($fp) { $video = explode("\n", fread($fp, filesize($tube))); }